# multidimensional array initialized with array returned by function

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have a problem with the following example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // this works
    int[] test1DArray = returnArray();

    int[][] test2DArray = new int[][] {

        // this does not work
        new int[]= returnArray(),

        // yet this does
        new int[] {1, 2 ,3}
}

private static int[] returnArray() {

    int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
    return a;
}
```

I am looking for a way to create a two-dimensional array, and have the second dimension be the array that is returned from a method. I do not understand why it does not work, as the error I am getting in Eclipse is

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

From my understanding, I am creating a new int array and assigning the returned value to it. Populating the second dimension array immediately like this

```
new int[] {1, 2 ,3}
```

works like a charm, and I am looking to do something similar with the array that's returned to me from `returnArray()`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

p/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use:

```
int[][] test2DArray = new int[][] {
    returnArray(),
    new int[] {1,2 ,3}
};
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Although @Eran has solved the problem, I feel you should understand why this went wrong.

When you initialize the contents of an array, you are basically returning values to it.

E.g.: `new int[]{1, 2, 3}` returns 1, 2, and 3 inside `test2Darray`, whereas `int[] n = new int[]{1, 2, 3}` is initializing and declaring an array inside `test2Darray`. The latter is not returning any primitive value inside the array, so it gives an error.

`returnValue()` is a method which does return a value (an integer array). So the control considers it equivalent to typing `new int[]{1, 2, 3}`.

Hence `new int[]{1, 2, 3}` and `returnValue()` work.

Comment: Thanks for the background, really helps to understand where I went wrong!